# (PYTHON) How to play audio file again after executing some code with pygame (pyglet or something similar)?

Tags: linux, audio, python-3.5

```
import time, os, sys, pygame

def some_function():
    if < condition >:
        time.sleep(5)
        pygame.mixer.init()
        alert = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/me/alert.wav')
        alert.play()
    else:
        < something >

some_function()

time.sleep(10)
```

Now here is a problem.
And I tried different combinations with pygame and pyglet.
pyglet.app.run() works but the rest of the script doesn't run!

```
pygame.mixer.init()
alert = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/me/alert.wav')
alert.play()
```

Comment: I'm on Linux Mint Serena btw

Comment: All I need just to repeat the alert again and the script is done.

Comment: It's unclear to me what does not work? Are the three last lines of code you posted working (pygame.mixer.init(); alert = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/me/alert.wav'); alert.play())?

Comment: It's working only once. Anyway, I've already moved on by replacing <pygame> with <webbrowser>. It's much more reliable and effective.  I knew it before and didn't want to involve external applications. Just didn't expect that pygame, pyglet libraries are not that good.